# Hard to sum series

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I sum this series :

$$a+\frac{1}{3}+3a-\frac{1}{6}+5a+\frac{1}{12}+.......$$upto $2n$ terms

**My try:** *I tried deducing the general term and summing the series with the help of general term but it got very complicated and unsolvable practically.*

Can you guys please show me a way to sum this series? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for giving this your time!

Comment: It looks like you've got two sums in there.  However, you don't really have enough data to be sure of the pattern.  $a(1+3+5+\dots+2n-1)$ and $\frac{1}{3}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{8}+\dots\right)$ (perhaps the next term should be $-\frac{1}{6}$?

Comment: That definetly has to be false because the answer given in my book is fairly simple.

Comment: I think I read it too quickly.  This is not the same as your other series.  The fractional terms may not be the alternating harmonic series (as was the case in [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2411056/weird-general-term)).  What is the general term for the fractions?

Comment: Can you please give a few more terms?  There are several possible patterns for the constants (is the sum geometric or harmonic)?

Comment: each set of 2 terms is $(2k+1)a-(-{1\over 3}(-{1\over 2})^k)$ k starting at 0.

Comment: Is not the same question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2411056/weird-general-term?

Answer (score 4):

Hint : $$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (2k+1)a+\frac{1}{3}(\frac{-1}{2})^k$$

$$ = 2a\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k+a\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}1+\frac{1}{3}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (\frac{-1}{2})^k$$

You end up with 2 sums of arithmetic progression terms and 1 sum of the terms of a geometric sequence.

Answer (score 2):

The sum of the arithmetic series is

$$n\frac{a+(2n-1)a}2=n^2a$$

while that of the geometric series is

$$\frac13\frac{1-\dfrac1{(-2)^n}}{1-\dfrac1{-2}}.$$

Comment: Yes, fairly simple I see, I messed up writing the general term. Thank you. +1.